# Чем отличаются классы Frame и JFrame, а также другие "с J" и "без J" в Java?

Tags: java, swing

Изучая Java, наткнулся на два, казалось бы, одинаковых класса `Frame` и `JFrame`. Оба класса нужны для создания окон приложения. Вот, что пишут про `Frame`:

> Контейнер `Frame` — это полноценное окно со строкой заголовка, в которой размещены кнопки контекстного меню, сворачивания окна в ярлык
>   и разворачивания во весь экран и кнопка закрытия. Заголовок окна
>   передается как параметр в конструктор, или задается методом
>   `setTitle(string title)`... ...Класс
>   `Frame` наследует около двухсот методов классов `Component`, `Container` и
>   `Window`. Менеджер компоновки по умолчанию — `BorderLayout`. Методы класса
>   `Frame` осуществляют доступ к элементам окна.

Кусочек про `JFrame`:

> В библиотеке `Swing` описан класс `JFrame`, представляющий собой окно с
>   рамкой и строкой заголовка (с кнопками «Свернуть», «Во весь экран» и
>   «Закрыть»). Оно может изменять размеры и перемещаться по экрану.
>
> Конструктор `JFrame()` без параметров создает пустое
>   окно. Конструктор `JFrame(String title)` создает пустое окно с
>   заголовком `title`.

По-моему это два идентичных класса. Также есть и другие такие "пары", например, `Button` и `JButton`, `Panel` и `JPanel`. В чем их отличия, и какие из них стоит использовать в коде?

Comment: те, что с J относятся к Swing (gui-библиотека), без J - к awt - визуально разный внешний вид виджетов

Comment: А если посмотреть его javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html, то сразу видно, какие методы/поля свои, какие унаследованы и от кого.